# Laravel 403 Forbidden Error after host move

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.7 project working fine, but I changed the host and i got this error:

> Laravel 403 Forbidden Error

I updated the `.htaccess` file with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but I still get the error.

Comment: have you checked the file permissions r/w for apache user and group?

Comment: yes its 755 also tried to change it to 777 gat same issue

Comment: maybe incorrect ownership or permissions on your web content files and folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `.htaccess` change to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

within your website folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what I did to fix this was to change permissions on the root folder of the project from 0644 to 0755.